# Integrate Bitcoin price in Google Sheets through Google Script

Tags: accounting, europe

How can I integrate the **real-time** value of the BTC/EUR pair to a Google sheet? What script can I use?

For ETH/USD I use Poloniex and a script for that, but there is no BTC/EUR pair on Poloniex.

This is the script I use for Poloniex and the ETH/USD pair:

> function getETHtoUSDTpoloniex() {
>   var url = "https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker";
>
> var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
>   var test = response.getContentText();
>
> var myjson = JSON.parse(test);
>   //var leng = myjson.data.length;
>
> var USDT_ETH = myjson["USDT_ETH"];
>
> var price = USDT_ETH.last;
>
> return parseFloat(price); }

Help please!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a library for this.
This is the one I use: [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cryptofinance/bhjnahcnhemcnnenhgbmmdapapblnlcn?hl=en)

Code would then be: `=CRYPTOFINANCE("COINMARKETCAP:ETH/USD", "price")`

The library explains itself rather well.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I was looking more to integrate without an add-on!